# Alternatives to MS project server

Tags: project-management, ms-project

I manage a small group and I'd keep my work breakdown in project.  However, it's difficult to provide my team with an adequate view into the project and ability to report on their progress.  I looked at MS Project Server (the sharepoint webpart) but it's an expensive proposition.

Has anyone had any experience with any other tool (commercial is fine) that helps team view and report on their work as managed by MS Project?  FWIW, I have looked at OpenProj and it appears to be a decent solution for viewing project files on the desktop.  Anything web-based, keeping in mind that I'd like people to report on their work not just view their work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A good web based hosted Project Management software that suits my EPM needs is called valleyspeak project server, which I found at www.valleyspeak.com. One of the main reasons why I like the software is the fact that I could continue to work in Microsoft Project 2007 while sharing my Microsoft Project plans with my teams.

Because it is a hosted service, I did not have to buy expensive software or deal with installation and maintenance headaches. The  functionality that I have with valleyspeak to manage my geographically dispersed teams works well for me.**

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Work Bench](http://www.openworkbench.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the tool rather technology, but i lately start  reading about [scrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrum) and find it interesting and useful.

Answer (score 1):

As "llya" suggested before maybe you should have a look at scrum as a methodology.

But on your question here you have some really good web-based alternatives:

- [acunote](http://www.acunote.com/) works pretty well also, and is web based and free for small teams.
- The one I personally use [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)
- scrumworks

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few open source apps to look at:

Joynet Connector
http://joyent.com/connector/

Clocking IT
http://www.clockingit.com/

RedMine
http://www.redmine.org/

You can host them your self, but the first two do offer hosted versions

Jason

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [www.ibnportal.co](http://www.ibnportal.com)m

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Projec.to [online Microsoft Project viewer](http://www.onlineprojectviewer.com/). It allows to upload MS Project files (.mpp), view them online, and share with others via browser, apart from Microsoft Project.

Disclosure: I'm one of the developers of this service.

Answer (score 0):

Daptiv might be worth a look. http://www.daptiv.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try InTask Professional (www.intaskrnd.com) - fast, cheap, tons of features, multi-user multi project, frequent updates. really good piece of software. alternatively you can try basecamp but it's much more expensive...